# proving a limit of relative frequencies in probability model

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

This is the basic idea, we imagine the chance set up in our world, say a coin that is flipped, which has some chance for the outcome $A$, where $A$ here could be 'the coin lands heads up'. Lets say for example that the probability for $A$ is $50\%$: we call this, $P(A)=0.5$. What this means, is that some digit from an equi-distributed sequence, for example $$L= \{0.1,0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,1, 0.11,0.12,.13,.14,\dots\}$$ is randomly selected and assigned to coin flip. If the digit, $L_i$, selected from $L$, is less than $P(A)$, then $A$ occurs. In other words, if the number $L_i$ that is part of $L$ (and is selected randomly from the ) sequence $L$ is smaller then $0.5$, then $A$ occurs (the coin lands heads up) otherwise $\neg A$ is the case (it lands tails).  Any given digit is possible, so the set up is in-deterministic, but I do not presume a measure over this digits, just that all of the digits are in the sample space (any given one could be selected). If I presumed a measure, my account would be circular. What is important is that this means that on the single case, if $A$ occurs; then if (hypothetically) $P(A)$ were higher then what it was, $A$ still would have occurred (because then  $P(A)$ would equal some number bigger than $0.5$, for example, $0.6$, and the digits of $L$ which are smaller then $0.6$ are a superset of the digits in $L$ which are smaller than $0.5$, so if we know that $A$ occurred with $P(A)=0.5$, we know that the digit selected was smaller than $0.5$, in which case we know that it is smaller than $0.6$, and any event $A$, such that $P(A)=0.6$, is such that it occurs if the digit is smaller than $0.6$).

In any case imagine we have an infinite number of these set ups, coins that is, each with the same chance for $A$, 'heads up'. I could use the language of possible worlds, but to get the point across we can imagine instead that this infinite number of coin flips occur at the same moment of time but at different points in space. Now suppose  this: the selection mechanism which determines the value $L_i$ for any given coin flip, also determines the values of $L_i$ for all of the other coin flips, and it does so by determining their order at the same time (so we resolve the ordering problem as well, because how the sequence is ordered, determines which coin flip gets which result). Suppose there are as many coins as there are number in $L$, and that each coin will get one of the values of $L$, and there is an exact 1-1 mapping so that for every number in $L$, there is one (and only one) coin which gets that number.

So lets say the coins are intially, prior to any outcome occurring, ordered according to their spatial position at time $t1$, $$M=[\text{coin 1 at position } x=0, \text{coin 2 at position } x=1, \text{coin 3 at position }x=2, \dots]$$ for an infinite number of coins. Now when each each and every coin gets mapped to one and only one digit, this is random, and it re-arranges the coins in the sequence according to which digit they get, ie if a coin gets the second digit in $L$, then that coin occupies the second position in the new sequence, call this $O$. The new sequences, $O$ is always ordered so that the ith member of it (that is of $O$) always corresponds to the ith member of $L$. The first coin in the new sequence, $O$, gets the first member of $L$, which is $0.1$, the second coin in this ordering, $O$ gets the second digit of $L$, which as we can see is $0.2$. Now it might be the 100th coin in the original sequence $M$ becomes the first coin in this new sequence $O$ , in which case it will occupy the first position in this new sequence, $O$, and will get the digit $0.1 $and its outcome will be $A$ as $0.1<P(A)=0.5$. So we know that whatever happens, we can determine a priori, what the outcomes of this new sequence $O$ will be, because we know that every set up has the same chance i.e. $0.5$, and we know by inspecting $L$, which digit the first element of $O$ will have, which digit the second element of $O$ will have etc, and we know $A$ occurs if that digit is smaller than $0.5$ and $\neg A$ occurs if that digit is bigger than $0.5$.

So we know what the outcome sequence will look like- (by outcome sequence we know what the sequence of outcomes, composed of $A$s and $\neg A$s will look like). Moreover, because $L$ is equidistributed (and thus the sequence of digits assigned to $O$is equi-distributed) we know already the outcome relative frequency of $A$. This being despite the fact that we do not know which coin will get which digit, not knowing which coin gets which outcome and not knowing how the spatial positions are re-ordered (because that is random, the coins which where beforehand ordered according to their spatial position are now re-ordered randomly according to which digit they get randomly assigned in $L$, so that if the coin in the 200th spatial position gets the first digit in $L$ (which is $0.1$), that same coin (in the 200th spatial position) will occupy the first position in $O$). The randomness of the re-ordering mirrors the randomness of the indeterministic process of any set up getting a particular outcome, because the process is united as one as and the same process (the re-ordering of each coin, determines uniquely its outcome).

By the outcome relative frequency $A$, I mean the relative frequency of $A$ as a limiting proportion of $O$'s which are $A$, as counted in sequence $O$ as $O$ limits to infinity; that is, as we consider nested increasing subsequence of $O$'s, where the first subsequence has the first element of $O$ and its digit, the second has the first and second elements of $O$ and their digits, the third has first three elements of and their digits, and where we count up the relative frequency in each such subsequence and see what it limits to. How do we do this:

We know that this limit is 0.5, we know a priori that the limiting relative frequency of $A$ in the  outcome sequence produced by $0$, will be $0.5$, because $L$ is equi-distributed. In other words, each member of $O$ gets mapped one to one with each of member of $L$, and the relative frequency of digits in $L$ that are smaller than $0.5$, is $0.5$, because its equi-distributed modulo $1$, and thus the relative frequency of the digits in $0$, which are smaller than $0.5$ will be $0.5$, because the  numbers assigned to $O$ correspond to a sequence which is identical to $L$, and the outcome sequence just is that sequence of $A$ and $\neg A$ determined by digits assigned to $O$. In other words, if we call the outcome sequence $U$, its first member is $A$ if the first member of $O$ gets a digit smaller than $0.5$, and this just occurs if the first member of $L$ is a digit smaller than $0.5$, as they are the same digit, otherwise the first member of $U$ gets $\neg A$, which means that $O$ gets assigned a digit greater than $0.5$ and this will only be the case if $L$ is such that its first element is greater than $0.5$. So according to the sequence we had $$L= \{0.1,0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,1, 0.11,0.12,.13,.14,\dots\}$$ we know that $U$ the sequence produced from $O$, as a result of the first member of $O$ getting the first member of $L$, the second member of $O$ getting the second member of $L$, will be $U:\{A, A, A, A, A, \neg A,\dots\}$ etc, because the first five digits are equal or small than $0.5$ which is the probability value of $A$ whilst the sixth member of $L$, as we can see is $0.6$ which is greater than $0.5$ which explains why the sixth member of $U$ is $\neg A$.

Now lets that this infinite trial across space occurs at time $t_0$. Let suppose there is another infinite sequence of coin tosses, again with $P(A)=0.5$ for each such coin toss at $t_1$, and lets supposed that its outcomes are produced in correspondence with the same procedure. Except that we now have two random re-orderings. To preserve, independence of the outcome result, so that proportion of $A$ on the second coin toss amongst that sequence of events whose first coin toss result is $A$, is $0.5$, and likewise if that first coin toss result is $\neg A$.

So what do we do, well we now have two equi-distributed sequences modulo one. What these do is change the ordering of the $A$ amongst the $A$'s in $U$, and the ordering of the $\neg A$ amongst the $\neg A$ in $U$ so that $U$, if we are only looking for $A$ and $\neg A$, $U$ remains identical as to how it looks (but remember these $A$ that are re-arranged correspond to elements of $O$ which are certain coin in certain spatial positions). In any case this- re-ordering preserves the original relative frequency but it finds all the $A$'s in $U$, and their positions, swaps their positions (so by swapping each $A$ gets its position in $U$ swapped but only insofar that its new position is always the position that some $A$ already had, it never gets swapped into the position of $\neg A$, then in accordance with this swap, that is after $U$ has been re-ordered. The first $A$ gets the first digit of an equidistributed sequence, the second $A$ (which may be for all I know the 7th element of this sequence) get the second digit in this equi-distributed sequence. Supposing that we use the same equidistributed sequence before, $L$, where $U$ is as again the outcomes of the first spatial trial of coins at the same time throughout space: ie
$$
A, A, A, A, A, \neg A,\dots
$$
Then we will have that the first five $A$'s get the first five digits of $L$. Now we do the same thing with the $\neg  A$'s, they get shuffled only amongst the $\neg A$ so that each $\neg A$'s position gets swapped only with the position of another $\neg A$, and then after this the first $\neg A$ in this shuffled sequence gets the first digit in $L$, the second $\neg A$ gets the second digit in $L$.

So if $U$ was $\{A, A, A, A, A, \neg A,\dots\}$ lets expand it to first eleven digits say to $$U = \{A, A,A,A,A, \neg A, \neg A, \neg A, \neg A, \neg A, A\}$$ (which assumes that $L$ is such that its 6th to tenth digits are all bigger than $0.5$) we get the following assortment of digits to this sequence, for the outcome of the second toss.
$$
\begin{array}{rccccccccccc}
U_2:\quad& 0.1,& 0.2,& 0.3,& 0.4,& 0.5,&  0.1,&  0.2,& 0.3,& 0.4,&  0.5, & 0.6\\
U:\quad &    A,&    A,&    A,&  A,&  A,& \neg A,&  \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A & A
\end{array}
$$
Which is in accordance with the fact that the first five digits of $L$ are $0.1$ through to $0.5$ and the first five $A$'s get the first five digits of $L$, and the first five $\neg A$ *also* get the first five digits of $L$.

Then those digits get translated into their outcomes if the digit is smaller than $P(A)$ then $A$, otherwise $\neg A$. So $U_2$ becomes
$$
\begin{array}{rccccccccccc|l}
U'_2:\quad& A,& A,& A,& A,& A,&  A,&  A,& A,& A,&  A,& \neg A & t=t_2\\
 &    A,&    A,&    A,&  A,&  A,& \neg A,&  \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A, &   A & t= t_1
\end{array}
$$

So $U_2$ is depicting two infinite sequences, the first sequence on the bottom is an infinite sequence of $A$'s across space at the fist point in time, and the second at the top, is an infinite sequence of $A$'s across space at the second point in time, lets call THAT time $t=t_2$. We have that all the $A$s in the same column occupy the same spatial position (although they are not  necessarily ordered according to their spatial position- nonetheless i am using standard space instead of an ordering amongst modal space/possible worlds for ease of mathematical tractability).

So we can see this as an infinite sequence of two coin tosses at different points in time, but at the same spatial position, where the spatial position changes as we move along the sequence, so that the first column might represent  a heads at space $x=100$ at $t_1$ and a heads at space $x=100$ at time $t_2$, and the second column might represent a heads at space $x=10$, and time  $t_1$, and a heads also at space $x=10$ and time $t_2$.

Elementary considerations we tell us, that the proportion of $n=2$ tuples individuated by their spatial position, so pairs of coins that are thrown at the same spatial position but one at $t=0$, and the other at $t=1$, which are such that both coins are $A$, is $25\%$. In other words, the if we consider the limiting proportion of columns, that  have $A$ in the first entry and $A$ in the second entry, if we consider that limit taken horizontally, we get $25\%$. I.e. the limiting relative frequency of couples of coin, which are such that the first is thrown at $t_0$ and the second $t_1$, which are such that the both such coins give $A$, as a limit taken across all such coins individuated by their ordering as given in $U$ (which designates the spatial positions) is $25\%$.

Now we have a third trial. And this time we get

$$
\begin{array}{rccccccccccc|l}
U'_2:\quad& A,& A,& A,& A,& A,&  A,&  A,& A,& A,&  A, & \neg A & t=t_2\\
 &    A,&    A,&    A,&  A,&  A,& \neg A,&  \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A, & A & t= t_1
\end{array}
$$

And we have four equidistributed sequence all equal to $L$, and we shuffle the positions of the $A$ $A$s, i.e. those elements which have $U$ $A$ at $t=t_1$, and $A$ $t=t_2$, amongst all the other $A$ $A$'s, and we shuffle the $A\neg A$ amongst the $A\neg A$s, and the $\neg A\neg A$ amongst the $\neg A\neg A$ and the $\neg AA$ amongst the $\neg AA$, so that $U_2$ appears to look the same as it did before. But this shuffle is changing the spatial positions of the coins, although we cant tell that by looking at simply $U_2$ which relative to any element being an $A$ or $\neg A$ it remains identical. Then the first $AA$, or first column whose bottom element is $A$ and top element is $A$, in this new sequence get the first digit of $L$, the second $AA$  gets the second digit in $L$; likewise the first $\neg AA$ gets the first element of $L$,the second $\neg AA$ gets  the second element of $L$. Finally, the first $A\neg A$ get the first element of $L$, the second $A\neg A$ the second the element of $L$, and the same for $\neg A \neg A$ (ie the first $\neg A\neg A$ gets the first digit in $L$, the second  $\neg A\neg A$ gets the second digit in $L$)

So we know what have an infinite sequence of columns with three elements, corresponding to $t=t_1$, $t=t_2$, $t=t_3$ respectively

$$
\begin{array}{rcccccccccc|l}
U_3:\quad& A,& A,& A,& A,& A,&  A,&  A,& A,& A,&  A & t=t_3\\
& A,& A,& A,& A,& A,&  A,&  A,& A,& A,&  A & t=t_2\\
 &    A,&    A,&    A,&  A,&  A,& \neg A,&  \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A,& \neg A & t= t_1
\end{array}
$$

And then the question is what proportion of such columns taken in the order of the sequence designated $t_1$, are such that all three elements of such a column have outcome $A$. It should $0.125$ although you cant see that from the diagram. So the proportion of such columns of size $n=3$, which have relative frequency $A$ across trials at $t=t_0$, $t=t_1$, $t=t_2$ as $100\%$, is $0.125$, in line with the binomial theorem

**Now suppose we continue this process to infinity. What proportion of columns taken in the order of the bottom sequence %t_1%, are such that the relative frequency of $A$'s in said column is $50\%$ (or approximately %50\%$). It appears to me to be $100\%$ or almost all in the combinatorial sense.**

My question is this true, and if so what technical mathematics do I need to prove this, so as to make it rigorous that is really all there it to it. There are other question for example whether the number of digits in the $L$ will be big enough to be split infinitely many (possible uncountably many times) and still represent a sequence of countable size or rather if we keep for re-ordering and partitioning the same sequence $L$, will the sequence that gets mapped to $L$ for each different combinations of possible outcomes at the different times, get too small, ie become finite but is supposed to be mapped to $L$ which is countably insofar as its an equidistributed modulo one sequence. But these are just niceties, the basic question, is as above in bold

Finally, can we make sense of this if we take $L$ to be an uncountable sequence, i.e. all the real number in $[0,1]$, or we must we introduce this measures for that. Isn't there a natural measure by which we can take an integral and say that it is equi-distributed - I ask this question because if I only work with an equidistributed sequence I may not be able to represent all real or irrational valued probabilities or frequences, some are going to be left out.

Comment: I think you'd benefit from learning to edit your stream of thought, I'd be surprised if anyone finishes this

Comment: I've just refactored all this large text and I ask you to use TeX commands further!